# Asynch WCF Data Services / OData

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf-data-services, odata

I am trying to write asynch call to a wcf data service but not sure how to read the object returned.

```
public IQueryable<T> Read(string TableName)
    {
        IQueryable<T> OdataResult=null;            

        IAsyncResult asyncresult = context.BeginExecute<T>(new Uri("/" + TableName, UriKind.Relative),
            (result) =>
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new OperationResultCallback(delegate
        {

            var result1 = new DataServiceCollection<T>(context.EndExecute<T>(result));

            OdataResult = result1.AsQueryable<T>();

        }), null);
            }, null);

        asyncresult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        asyncresult.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();

        return OdataResult;}
```

ODataResult is always giving me null :(

Comment: I have debug it but not able to get any clue. I am guessing it is something related to Thread where I have to pass the value to my main thread but not sure how to do that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used "Task" instead of "Dispatcher" and it shared the Data via "Result" property with My main thread.